# Generate rst files and directories mirroring the package and module tree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I'm trying to generate documentation for my library. Since the library directory structure is quite big, I want Sphinx to generate the `.rst` files as a nested directory that mirrors the package and module structure.

#### The library structure:

```
pyflocker/
├── __init__.py
├── ciphers/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── backends/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── _asymmetric.py
│   │   ├── _symmetric.py
│   │   ├── cryptodome_/
│   │   │   ├── AES.py
│   │   │   ├── ChaCha20.py
│   │   │   ├── ECC.py
│   │   │   ├── Hash.py
│   │   │   ├── RSA.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── _serialization.py
│   │   │   └── _symmetric.py
│   │   └── cryptography_/
│   │       ├── AES.py
│   │       ├── Camellia.py
│   │       ├── ChaCha20.py
│   │       ├── DH.py
│   │       ├── ECC.py
│   │       ├── Hash.py
│   │       ├── RSA.py
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── _serialization.py
│   │       └── _symmetric.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── exc.py
│   ├── interfaces/
│   │   ├── AES.py
│   │   ├── Camellia.py
│   │   ├── ChaCha20.py
│   │   ├── DH.py
│   │   ├── ECC.py
│   │   ├── Hash.py
│   │   ├── RSA.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── modes.py
└── locker.py
```

Till now I was using `sphinx-apidoc -e -o ...` to generate the documentation within the `docs/source/` folder.
But this doesn't work as expected.

#### Expected Results:

Documentation generated as a nested directory. The files have been removed to keep the backbone only.

```
docs/source/
└── ciphers/
    └── backends/
        ├── cryptodome_/
        └── cryptography_/
```

#### Actual results:

The whole module name is retained.

```
docs/source/
├── ...  # skipping boilerplate files
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.AES.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.ChaCha20.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.ECC.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.Hash.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.RSA.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptodome_.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.AES.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.Camellia.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.ChaCha20.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.DH.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.ECC.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.Hash.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.RSA.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.cryptography_.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.backends.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.base.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.exc.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.AES.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.Camellia.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.ChaCha20.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.DH.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.ECC.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.Hash.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.RSA.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.interfaces.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.modes.rst
├── pyflocker.ciphers.rst
├── pyflocker.locker.rst
└── pyflocker.rst
```

Is there any way to generate the doc as a directory tree?

Comment: I did not see any such option in the docs for either sphinx-apidoc or sphinx-autogen. I also did not see any extension in https://github.com/sphinx-contrib

Comment: This can be done with a single function using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). If you use `sphinx-apidoc -e` getting 1 file per module, put all the file names (their names being fully qualified helps) in a dictionary and [stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem). Afterwards create one directory for each parent and place the files where you want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do so using [sphinx-nested-apidoc](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-nested-apidoc/).
It mirrors the original package structure and generates appropriate files.

Note that it does not edit the files or the links within it. It just renames or moves them.

Answer (score 1):

What you specify isn't currently possible.

1. `sphinx-apidoc` will not create directories mirroring your package/file structure.
2. `sphinx-apidoc` will not distribute `.rst` files along several directories mirroring your package/file structure.

Notice the `sphinx-apidoc` signature, you can specify one input path for modules, and one output path for the `.rst` files:

> [Synopsis](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#synopsis)
>
> `sphinx-apidoc [OPTIONS] -o <OUTPUT_PATH> <MODULE_PATH> [EXCLUDE_PATTERN …]`

You'll have to write your own script to recurse into your file system and execute `sphinx-apidoc` once for every package/directory with `<MODULE_PATH>` mirroring `<OUTPUT_PATH>`.

This may seem counter-intuitive, however the Python philosophy is:

> [The Zen of Python - PEP 20](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#synopsis)
>
> Flat is better than nested.

Arguably it is more convenient to have `sphinx-apidoc` produce the `.rst` files with dotted names mirroring the package/module structure, because you get an overview of the packages at a glance and it tends to save clicking.

If you want to organize some `.rst` files into directories afterwards it is possible to link them, at the time of this writing it is however not possible to generate such a tree automatically using `sphinx-apidoc` in a single execution.

Comment: It is possible now using [sphinx-nested-apidoc](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-nested-apidoc/). I will mention it in my answer.